# A gas immersed in a higher-pressure gas: spherical shape?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, ideal-gas, equilibrium

I'm considering a bubble of gas of some arbitrary shape immersed in another gas of *higher* pressure. There is no gravity (and hence no buoyancy), the gases are ideal (so there are no attractive forces between particles), and the gases can't mix --- we might consider them separated by some thin, flexible surface, or something along those lines. (The surface shouldn't play a role in the physics; I'm *not* thinking of an elastic surface such as a balloon.)

My intuition is that the bubble will be compressed into a smaller volume until its pressure matches that of the surrounding gas, and that its final shape will be spherical.
However, I'm struggling to find an explicit physical argument to support the suspicion that the equilibrium situation enforces sphericity on the bubble.

Is the sphere a minimum energy configuration? Of what potential? Or is the problem ill-defined?

Thank you! :)

Comment: If the separating surface plays no role in the physics, then surface tension is ruled out. Is diffusion also ruled out?

Comment: Is your question whether the boundary will tend to become more spherical as the low-pressure gas compresses? Or is your question whether the spherical shape remains a stable equilibrium state even after the pressure difference is gone? If the second, I think the initial pressure difference is a red herring.

Comment: @EdV: I don't want the gases to mix and become one, to keep the notion of the bubble as a separate object well-defined. If there's an solution that doesn't require diffusion, that would be great, but I'm also interested in a solution in which it does feature.

Comment: @rob: My question is your first suggestion: why (if at all) should the bubble become spherical as it approaches equilibrium?
Perhaps the question why it would _stay_ spherical is another side of the same coin: if 'deviations' from sphericity are somehow suppressed in equilibrium, then that same mechanism could lead to sphericity in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

> the bubble will be compressed into a smaller volume until its pressure matches that of the surrounding gas

Exactly true.  The forces on either side of your "boundary" are unequal, so it will move in response.

> and that its final shape will be spherical

We'd need some reason for that.  A real bubble has cohesive forces producing surface tension, or an energy cost for the surface.  If this magical boundary doesn't have an energy cost, there's no reason for it to be spherical.  That also sort of means there's no reason for it to be contiguous.  If it can pinch without cost, then it can separate as well.

So if you can come up with a physical reason for this bubble to remain whole, then that reason may well cause a spherical shape.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: Thank you! If I understand you correctly, you say that the physical properties of the separating surface are in fact crucial to deduce the equilibrium shape, and so the question has no answer for a 'magical' surface.
I'm assuming that with an ever-so-slightly non-zero surface tension $\gamma$ the equilibrium situation will always be a sphere.

Comment: Given these are non-interacting ideal gases, that seems correct.